# How do i convert a csv file to a db REACT-NATIVE

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create an app that pulls and pushes to and from a remote server a bunch CSV and a txt file with data in it and convert it into a SQLLite database that I can read/write/query. The txt file contains timestamps that I will be using so when the app pulls again from the server it'll take only the updated values from the server after that certain timestamp (so I don't have to completely redownload all the data). However, I also want to be able to send data back to the server from the database!

So far, I have successfully implemented the Fetching of the data but I am stuck on how to convert my csv files into a db file for React-Native. I want to use `react-native-sqlite-storage` to then read/write/query the data.

However, the `react-native-sqlite-storage` requires a `.db` file and I only have `.csv` files.

I was thinking that I could convert the csv file into a JSON and then somehow convert the json into a db?

I'm confused whether or not my approach is efficient or is there any other efficient way to implement this ! Thank you so much